# How get list of User Installed and Running apps for Task Manager?

Tags: sorting, system, task

I'm want make a Task Manager and do not understand: how to sort list of running apps by SystemProc and UsersApps.

Now use this procedure:

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService( ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
        List<RunningAppProcessInfo> procInfos = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
        for(int i = 0; i < procInfos.size(); i++){


            //PackageInfo p = packs.get(i); 
            lvAdapter.add(procInfos.get(i).processName);

        }
```

This example gives ALL running apps and I don't know how to sort the data.
Maybe anyone knows another way for getting and sorting an apps list?

Answer (score 0):

Implement Custom Comparor Class

```
public class CustomComparator implements Comparator<RunningAppProcessInfo> {
    @Override
    public int compare(MyObject o1, MyObject o2) {
        return o1.Field.compareTo(o2.Field);
    }
}
```

and then you call it like `Collections.sort(procInfos, new CustomComparator())`